# CSS Fixed Positioning and Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a navigation menu on my site which will transition to a full-screen slide-out menu whenever the user uses the site on a mobile device via media queries. However if the screen height is vertically too small to display the contents of the menu (e.g. wearables) I'd like the menu to have its own scrollbar.

**Problem:** The menu fits itself to the screen with a fixed position that is 0 pixels from all sides. However, even if I have a minimum height and an `overflow: visible|auto` property assigned to the menu, it still never shows its own scrollbar. Only the body one shows.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/fbhh15fo/ Try resizing the frame of the preview area to see what I mean.

**Question:** Anyone know how to get the menu to show its own scrollbar, if the screen height is too small. Again this menu has a fixed position which is 0 pixels from all sides.

Comment: In JSFiddle scrolbar displayed .

Comment: In the provided demo, the scroll-bar belongs to the absolutely positioned menu itself, not the body.

Comment: Instead of min-height in ul just use max-height so that the scroll bar will be visible for ul even

Comment: huh... my application must have some minor differences, since it really doesn't display there

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 Thank you, but, unfortunately, no.

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 Chrome. It turns out I was able to get it in a manner similar to yours. I added the solution in as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will make the menu max out at the viewport height.

Add

```
max-height: 100vh;
```

to the `ul` css section

```
ul {
    /* Lots of declarations */
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/fbhh15fo/2/))

Answer (score 0):

You need to change min-height to max-height in ul :

Before Change:

```
ul {
    background: #191919;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #EDEDED;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    **min-height: 150px;**
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

After Change :

```
ul {
    background: #191919;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #EDEDED;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    **max-height: 150px;**
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fbhh15fo/3/)

Comment: Yes, that adds a scrollbar, but completely defeats the purpose of having it. It isn't there just to be there, but appear when the screen height is too small to support it.

Comment: ya exactly you need to add it over media query for your specific screen

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that by adding a media query, and specifying the height of the menu to 100% worked!

```
@media screen and (max-height: 380px) {
    ul.nav {
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```